# Stopwatch until correct imput is enterd

Tags: python, python-3.x, stopwatch

I want to make a stopwatch that count how much time it took you to enter a correct imput. Are there modules that can help with is?

I have already tried using import time and import timer
I am making a speed typer and i want to know how long it took you to type.

Comment: How you're evaluating that provided input is correct and required one?

Comment: Never mind got it working

Comment: Good. Any way you can answer your own question. Share your solution will might help other in need.

Comment: used a bit of chatgpt's help

Answer (score -1):

```
from random import * 
from timer import *
import time
list = ["inch","multiply","nothing","course","stay","wheel","full","force","blue","object","decide","surface","deep","moon","island","foot","system","busy","test","record","boat","common","gold","possible","plane","stead","dry","wonder","laugh","thousand","ago","ran","check","game","shape","equate","hot","miss","brought","heat","snow","tire","bring","yes","distant","fill","east","paint","language","among","grand"]
a = randint(0,49)
c = list[a]
# Define the correct input
correct_input = c

# Start measuring time
start_time = time.time()

# Prompt the user for input until they enter the correct one
while True:
    print(c)
    user_input = input("Write the word: ")
    if user_input == correct_input:
        break

# Calculate the time taken
end_time = time.time()
sek = end_time - start_time

print(f"You wrote the word in {sek:.2f} sek.")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).